# How to disable certain days and dates in MUI react datepicker based on a json array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, materialize

I have Laravel app that returns a json response of dates and days of the week that should be disabled in the datepicker

For example this is my datesOff constant when I `console.log()` it `['2022-05-08', '2022-05-11', '2022-05-19']`

And This is daysOff constant when I `console.log()` it `[3, 6]`

So how do I disable both returned dates and days(wednesday and sunday in this case)

```js
    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(bookingUrl).then((response) => {
        setDaysOff(response.data.daysOff);
        setDatesOff(response.data.datesOff);
        setBooked(response.data.booked);
      })
    }, []);

<LocalizationProvider locale={hr} dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <DatePicker
            label="Date"
            disablePast={true}
            minDate={minDate}
            maxDate={maxDate}
            value={date}
            shouldDisableDate={//What do i to here
            }
            onChange={(newDate) => {
            setDate(newDate);
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
```

Answer (score 2):

Appreciate the answer from [Dmitriif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14190690/dmitriif) the code is working fine except one issue with the code is the array of **dates** not disabling the dates from the array such as date: 2020-05-19 and It's disabled the 2020-05-20 to fix that you need to update the one line of code:

```
const stringifiedDate = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

to:

```
const stringifiedDate = dayjs(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

install **dayjs** and import in your file. and you are good to go.

thanks again to [Dmitriif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14190690/dmitriif)

Answer (score 1):

`DatePicker` has [renderDay](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/) prop which we can use to customize the day cells of the calendar. It takes 3 arguments, the first one is the Date object, which we can use to compare with the array of dates that should be disabled:

```
  const dates = ["2022-05-08", "2022-05-11", "2022-05-19"];

  const customDayRenderer = (
    date: Date,
    selectedDates: Array<Date | null>,
    pickersDayProps: PickersDayProps<Date>
  ) => {
    const stringifiedDate = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    if (dates.includes(stringifiedDate)) {
      return <PickersDay {...pickersDayProps} disabled />;
    }
    return <PickersDay {...pickersDayProps} />;
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        renderDay={customDayRenderer}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-datepicker-disabling-dates-tw60bo?file=/demo.tsx:537-1248)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the answer by Dmitriif but it has been changed because it caused many renders through the process of selecting a date.

```
const customDayRenderer = (
    date: Date,
    selectedDates: Array<Date | null>,
    pickersDayProps: PickersDayProps<Date>
) => {
    amountOfExercises.forEach(day => {
        selectedDates.push(new Date(day.exerciseDate))
    });

    return <PickersDay {...pickersDayProps}  sx={{
        [`&&.${pickersDayClasses.selected}`]: {
          backgroundColor: "#EBEBE4",
          cursor: 'not-allowed'
        }
      }} />;
};
```

---

```
<DatePicker
   disablePast={true}
   label="Exercise Date"
   **renderDay={customDayRenderer}**
   value={dateValue}
   onChange={(newDateValue) => {
     setNewDateValue(newDateValue);
   }}
   renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
/>
```

The `amountOfExercises` is a JSON array and inside the `forEach`. I'm extracting the date I want to disable and push it to the `selectedDates` array.

After doing this you will notice that the background color of the dates you want disable had changed meaning the `DatePicker` "knows" what dates are supposed to be selected.

In order to give the user a feeling that the `selectedDates` are not available for the (disabled) selection I've added the `sx` attribute which gives a `lightgray` background color and a cursor which is not allowed.

The date variable inside `customDayRender` in my code is never read but when trying to delete it I've got an error that the `renderDay` method can't find the day to render